# SharePoint 2016 activate Publishing feature failure

Tags: publishing-site, 2016

I have a new installation of SharePoint 2016 (Standard). I am not able to create any Site collections that use the publishing feature. Tested Enterprise Search Center and Publishing Portal.

For further investigation I created a site collection based on Team site template. I then went in and enabled the Site collection publishing feature and got access denied.

Create a new Team Site Site collection and checking permission on site collection (remembering bug from previous versions), Masterpages inherits permissions and root site collection permissions are all missing. Only one listed is the "owner" name with Full Control. I then add "everyone" with Read access and activate feature successfully.

That works well for activating the feature, but does not work for the publishing template since it is baked in.

This is not my first deployment for 2016 I don't recall my other client's deployments having this issue.Has anyone else experienced this and/or does anyone have a workaround, or a solution?

Comment: Have you added the portal super user/reader to the Web Application PropertyBag as well as User Policy?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up rebuilding the web application. When I went to delete the existing web application, it did not complete well and there appears to be some corrupt security settings. After rebuilding the web application, this was all resolved.